# RegEx matching $1 tokens

Tags: java, regex, regexp-replace

lets suppose I have the following string
"$1 $1 10 20 $11 3$1 30 $1 10 $1"

I want to replace $1 whenever it is in the beginning of the string, end of string or between two spaces.
As an example, replacing $1 with 10, would produce:
"10 10 10 20 $11 3$1 30 10 10 10"

I am trying with the following expression:
"(\s\$1\s)|(^\$1\s)|(\s\$1$)"

Unfortunately, I'm not able to match the 2nd $1, as the space character seems to be captured by the first match. The result with this expression is:
"10 **$1** 10 20 $11 3$1 30 10 10 10"

I am not experienced with regex, and I'm probably missing something here. How can i correct the expression?
(Java)
thank you

Comment: You can use `"(?<!\\S)\\$1(?!\\S)"`. Or, `text.replaceAll("\\s*(?<!\\S)\\$1(?!\\S)", "").trim()`

Comment: thanks - that first expression seems to work!